# Fluent nHibernate - unfriendly many-to-one reference name

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I define my data model using Fluent nHibernate POCO classes + mappings. I'm also using nHiberate schema to create database schema.
All is working fine but there is one unpleasent fact.
When I use many-to-one reference referece is named by something similair to GUID instead of any descriptive name.
Here's a piece of SQL:

```
alter table [Odbiorca] 
        add constraint FK291D244B5D9E8115 
        foreign key (Adr_IdKraj) 
        references [Kraj]
```

I want nHiberate to generate something like Sql Studio does like `[FK_Odbiorca_Kraj]`.
Is it doable by overridding mappings or by creating any convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Fluent, but with regular XML mapping you just can use the `foreign-key` attribute:

```
<many-to-one 
  name="Kraj" 
  class="Kraj" 
  column="Adr_IdKraj" 
  foreign-key="FK_Odbiorca_Kraj"/>
```

Comment: FNH: `References(x => x.Kraj).ForeignKey("FK_Odbiorca_Kraj");`

Comment: @James Gregory: How do you accomplish the same using a convention?

Comment: See: [ForeignKeyConvention in the wiki](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Available_conventions#ForeignKeyConvention).